# Using Chrome Remote Desktop, can I transfer files between computers?

Tags: google-chrome, file-transfer, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to transfer files between remotely connected computers with the Google Chrome Remote Desktop plugin?

If not, is there a simple way I can transfer files between connected computers?

Comment: Does this extension even support this feature?

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like it. From the webstore: 'Computers can be made available ... for remote access to your applications and files.'

Comment: @Mcalex But that has nothing to do with a transfer though.

Comment: Yeah I see.  I just figured if you could access it you should be able to save it.  On closer read, it doesn't look like it is available as a feature

Comment: @mcalex - That doesn't indicate files can be transfered.

Comment: @MonteCristo- If u want to transfer files there are many other options available to u. Chrome Remote Desktop is an extension which would be a suitable alternative to Teamviewer.

Comment: @Simon Even in 2012, TeamViewer was far more full-featured than Chrome Remote Desktop.

Comment: 7 years later....YES YOU CAN! IT'S NOW POSSIBLE: https://superuser.com/a/1453775/425838

Comment: @MonteCristo can you change the accepted answer please?

Comment: Change the accepted answer Monte

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, yes you can. As of very recently (This week? This month? Just now today? [This is the first time I've seen it]) Chrome Remote Desktop has moved from being a stand-alone program you download and launch through the Chrome Store, to an in-browser app you launch from a website: https://remotedesktop.google.com.

[Tested 27 June 2019]

With this change comes a brand-new file transfer feature! When you log in you have this menu on the right-hand side of your screen:

[image]

If you don't see that, hover on the right until you see a little blue arrow pointing to the left, and click it, as this menu is hide-able.

### 1. To download from remote to local:

To **Download a file from the remote machine to your local machine (host)** click the "Download file" button. It will open up a "Download File" file manager window on the remote machine. Choose a file and click "Open." The file is transferred through the network and a GUI file manager "Save File" window will magically open up on your local (host) machine. Choose a location and save the file.

Done. The file is on your local machine in the folder you chose to save it in.

### 2. To upload from local to remote:

To **Upload a file from your local (host) machine to your remote machine**, click the "Upload file" button. It will open an "Open File" file manager window on your local machine. Choose a file (*bug alert: you MUST click on the file again with your mouse even if it is already selected or else this won't work for me*) and click "Open". Under the "File Transfer" dialog shown above, you'll see an "Uploading" indicator show up with a file transfer progress bar. When completed, you'll see the following notification pop up on the bottom of your remote desktop screen: "Upload complete. Look for the file on the remote device's desktop."

[image]

Done. The file is on your remote computer's desktop.

Comment: I just tried it on macOS Catalina, but the right-side menu didn't have a File Transfer section. Looks like either the feature was removed or it's not available on macOS.

Comment: @AlexWally I haven't tested on MacOS, but maybe your MacOS is an old version and only supported an old version of Chrome.  I just tried  Chrome Version 103.0.5060.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)  in Windows and it worked..   Is the version of Chrome on your Mac as late/up to date as that one?

Answer (score 29):

This is kind of a joke answer but since copy and paste is supported between the target and the host, the geeky way to copy a file *without* resorting to intermediate cloud storage would be to:

1. On the source: use any available encoder to convert the file to Base64/UUEncode so you can copy the data with Ctr+C.
2. On the target: paste the data to a text file and decode it with any available decoder.

### Python-based solution

First, on the source machine fire up a Python console and type:

```shell
 base64data = open('myfile.jpg','rb').read().encode('base64')
 open('myfile.txt','w').write(base64data)
```

Next, open the file `myfile.txt` with a text editor and copy the contents. Then on the target machine paste the contents into a new file named `myfile.txt` and in a console type:

```shell
data = open('myfile.txt').read().decode('base64')
open('myfile.jpg','wb').write(data)
```

These snippets can be extracted to scripts in order to avoid typing every time.

### GUI based solution (Windows)

If you don't have Python or if both your machines are running Windows and you have [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) installed then the steps are simpler:

1. On the source: select your file and then pick **Files** > **Encode file**. A corresponding `.b64` will be created in the other panel - open it (<kbd>F3</kbd>) and copy the contents (<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>).
2. On the target: paste into a new file with `.b64` extension and then use **Files** > **Decode file**.

Another alternative app is [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the built-in mimetools plugin that does base64 encoding/decoding (Plugins -> Mime Tools > 64 Encode/Decode).

### Command line solutions (OSX, Linux, Windows)

OSX and most Linux systems typically come with more than one flavour of console base64 encoders. This should work ootb without having to install anything:

```shell
## encode to base64
openssl base64 -in myfile.jpg -output myfile.jpg.b64
## OR on some systems `-out` should be used instead of `-output`
openssl base64 -in myfile.jpg -out myfile.jpg.b64

## encode to base64 on Windows (recent versions)
certutil -encode myfile.jpg myencodedfile.jpg.b64

## decode from base64
openssl base64 -d -in myfile.jpg.b64 -output myfile.jpg
## OR on some systems `-out` should be used instead of `-output`
openssl base64 -d -in myfile.jpg.b64 -out myfile.jpg

## decode base64 on Windows
certutil -decode myencodedfile.jpg.b64 myfile.jpg
```

Omitting the `-output...` part will print to standard output.

Another ootb utility present both in OSX and Ubuntu:

```shell
## encode to base64
base64 < myfile.jpg > myfile.jpg.b64


## decode from base64 (Linux) (note the lowercase 'd')
base64 -d < myfile.jpg.b64 > myfile.jpg

## decode from base64 (OSX) (note the uppercase 'D')
base64 -D < myfile.jpg.b64 > myfile.jpg
```

### Piping directly to clipboard (avoiding intermediary files)

It is possible to encode directly to the clipboard if you have the corresponding command line tools on the source/target OS.

On OSX there are the built-in [`pbcopy`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) and [`pbpaste`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html), on Linux (in xorg), there is [xclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard), and on Windows there is [clip.exe](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/5182-tip-use-clip-exe-manage-clipboard-cmd.html), which means that encoding a file to clipboard can be simplified to  (e.g. for OSX):

```shell
base64 < myfile.jpg | pbcopy
```

### And the proper way...

Jokes aside now.. If you need to transfer files between two machines (no matter what you use to connect) then use SSH which provides [`scp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy). If one or both boxes are behind firewalls/routers then use a jump server (i.e. an internet-exposed server, could be a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)). You'll need to have an always-on link from your destination box to the jump server, configure port forwarding and then use SCP over the forwarded port on the jump server. In a A->B->C hop scenario you'll need an SSH client on **A**, and running SSH servers on both **B** and **C**.

Once you have the outgoing connection and [port forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) configured from box **C**  (which can be tricky if you've never done it before) you can connect over SSH from box **A** with a profile defined in your `~/.ssh/config` file similar to:

```shell
Host jump
    Hostname hostname_C
    User username_C
    Port portnumber_C
    ProxyJump username_B@hostname_B:portnumber_B
```

Once you have it all set up you can copy files/folders simply with:

```shell
scp -r /some/local/dir jump:remote_dir
```

or from remote to local:

```shell
scp -r jump:remote_dir/subdir /my/local/machine/path
```

`remote_dir` will be relative to the user's home.

> <sup>NOTE: This does not cover all the steps, as this is beyond the scope of the original question, but you can use for example Chrome Remote Desktop in order to establish the SSH link from your box C to box B (the jump server), and then from box A 'transparently' connect to C via B.</sup>

---

> <sup>And finally, if you want a nicer text-mode GUI than `scp` then consider using Midnight Commander — [`mc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) (`apt install mc`) where you can connect e.g. with **Left** -> **Shell Link**: type your target box user@IP or your alias configured in `~/.ssh/config` such as `jump` in the example above.</sup>

Transfer files over SSH with Midnight Commander:

[image: Transfer files over SSH with Midnight Commander]

Comment: Even though this does not actually fix my issue. (My file is over 100mb and clipboard will not accept that). I feel I need to upvote this anyway. Just because this answer exists.

Comment: For big files a possible solution might be to (1) compress the file to reduce size (2) split to maximum accepted size, e.g. `split -b 10m myfile.zip` _(just a guess, no idea what the maximum allowed size is)_ (3) base64 encode the files (4) copy contents one by one (5) decode and re-assemble the parts on the target machine. Even though steps 1,2,3,5 can be scripted, step 4 will still have to be done manually, although I guess even this can be automated with something like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) although this can be get way too ridiculous...

Comment: Clipboard share is *not* supported if the remote client is a mobile host (iOS or Android).

Comment: @RossPresser: the answer is more of a joke than an actual solution; a proper solution would be to set up an SSH tunnel, and if one or both machines are behind intranets then use your own jump server — then you can mount the remote machine to your local file system (or the other way round).

Answer (score 13):

Yes. This answer from Gabriel Staples, answers it https://superuser.com/a/1453775/146314 and the accepted answer should be changed to that. It is now possible in Chrome remote desktop, to transfer files.

[Details about Chrome RDP](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649523)

<s>This can't be done. As a work around, you could always email it to yourself though, or use Google Drive / drop box or similar.</s>

Comment: you write ". As a work around, you could always email it to yourself though, or use Google Drive / drop box or similar." <-- terrible solution.. dropbox and google drive are limited in capacity.

Comment: This answer is so misleading.  It looks like you are saying it can't be done.. Quite frankly you should delete this answer.  Or use cross through, and say the correct answer is https://superuser.com/a/1453775/146314

Answer (score 3):

To transfer files, just use your Google Drive.  You have to be logged into your Google account in order to use Chrome Remote Desktop, so just open Google Drive, drop your file into it.  Once it uploads, open Google Drive on your remote computer and pull it out of Google Drive to the desktop or folder of your choice!

Comment: What about giving support via Chrome RDP?

Comment: no this is a terrible solution because there is a file size limit

Comment: @ZverevEvgeniy Chrome RDP has two options, access(for you to deal with your own computers, so, more permanent codes), and support(for you to deal with other peoples computers, a bit like  classic use of teamviewer,, temporary codes). I've tested chrome remote desktop access, and it has a right hand menu as one of the answers here shows. Chrome remote desktop, support, probably has an option too