# Is it possible to send files in Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, chrome-remote-desktop

I want to send files in Chrome Remote Desktop. In both directions.

Is this possible?

There is a sidebar in Chrome Remote Desktop for various settings but I couldn't find a menu to send and receive files.

Comment: No, but typically you are both logged into Chrome as your respective Chrome users, so you can send via Drive or Gmail with little delay.

Comment: TL;DR - Yes you can. Follow this [Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1453775/1243507) for a details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is **NO**

Although Chrome Remote Desktop allows you to send files by the sidebar the PC you are controlling can't send files back to you

The only software, as far as I know that can do this is TeamViewer.

TeamViewer its way more capable than Chrome remote desktop, you could use Chrome for some basic stuff, but TeamViewer it's the way to go if you are planning to do more technical stuff in the PC you are controlling.

[image: File transfer]

Comment: I know TeamViewer is the best program but it's not free for commercial use. And it's not cheap.